# Entity framework - LINQ JOIN not working

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, navigation-properties

I have a gridview displaying Patient data but I need to use two tables - Currently I am binding it with only the Patient table and its showing Gender, Ethnicity etc ( with numbers ) but I need to get those data from the Ref table. I tried to do join then bind it but I did not work and I was told Navigation property will do the Job but not single tutorial helped me.

Help and advise will be appreciated.

Example of Patient and Ref table

```
Patient Table 

Patient ID    Patient Name    Gender     Ethnicity   

    1          John            0           1

Ref Table 

 Reference ID    Domain      Code    Description

       1         Gender       0       Male
       2         Gender       1      Female
       3         Ethnicity    1      White
       4         Ethnicity    2      Black
```

and here is the Join that I tried

```
   Dim Testing = from x In db.Patient, y In db.ref where y.Domain = "Gender" 
   or y.Domain = "Ethnicity"
   Select x.PatientID, x.PatientName, y.Gender, y.Ethnicity

   gvPatient.DataSource = Testing
   gvPatient.DataBind()
```

Comment: If all your lookup values are in one table, you have bigger problems.  You need separate Entities for Gender and Ethnicity.  You can get Join() to work here, but fixing your model (and hopefully your database) is better.

Comment: David, If I had different tables. I can easily do join however I am asked by my supervisor to do it all in Ref table so I am not sure how to join column in one table and row in another table then select from those two tables. Maybe there is a way using Navigation property but I dont know and the Join seems hard. any helpful links would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you create multiple views on top of the single reference table?

Comment: I am just going to read about it. Thanks!

Comment: CREATE VIEW [Current Gender] AS
         SELECT Code, Description
             FROM db.Ref
         WHERE Domain = "Gender";                                                                     My understanding that " Current Gender should be virtual so it wont be added to the database however I can query the table or have Join easily then just bind it the gridview? I just wanted confirmation before doing anything that cause issues to the existing database! Thanks:)

Comment: I'd probably just call it Gender, but yea.  Then create an entity for that and mark the Code with a KeyAttribute.   Then you can add a Navigation Property on Patient.  The view is a permanent database object, but doesn't store any data.

Comment: Thanks very much! you gave me some good ideas!

Comment: You can add it as an answer and I will accept it. It is pretty useful it might helps others too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create views for each of the lookups like.

```
CREATE VIEW Gender 
AS 
SELECT Code, Description 
FROM .Ref 
WHERE Domain = 'Gender'
```

Then create entities for each lookup, marking the Code property with a KeyAttribute.